# replace search test to icon search

Tags: php, html, debugging

I can replace search text with search icon at chrome developer tool element by replacing

```html
<input type="submit" value="search">
```

with this:

```html
<button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></> 
</button>
```

this is theme searchform.php

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

?><form role="search" method="get" class="pojo-form form-search" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
 <label for="s">
  <span class="sr-only"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'pojo' ); ?></span>
 </label>
 <input type="search" title="<?php _e( 'Search', 'pojo' ); ?>" name="s" value="<?php echo ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) ? $_GET['s'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search...', 'pojo' ); ?>" class="field search-field">
 <button value="<?php _e( 'Search', 'pojo' ); ?>" class="search-submit button" type="submit"><?php _e( 'Search', 'pojo' ); ?></button>
</form>
```

My question is
How can I modify searchform.php in order to to get the search icon
https://krush.co.il/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do I need to change in my searchform.php or in my child theme function.php in order to get the search icon instead of search text

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the theme's search.php code? Did you try replacing the code you mention here and it looked right but didn't submit?

Comment: see above my searchform.php (I think that search.php is not the one I need to change)
I do not see "<input type="submit" value="search">" in my searchform.php in order to replace it

Comment: Right you are, and even this file may not be included as the form; it could be created by a function. Depending on how the theme is wired up I sometimes copy the search form HTML once it is rendered and then replace the function call in the appropriate template part. Do you see a function call or include in header.php that is creating the search form? Perhaps you can paste your html with the better button there.

Comment: I am searching for <input type="submit" at all theme and plugins files and I don't find where is it???!!!

Comment: It's being built dynamically. Looks like it is in a woocommerce template or header.php

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button class="search-submit button" type="submit"><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></button>
```

You don't need to have both the value of the button and the inner html of the button tag. You just want to change the search text with your icon html.

Comment: I have changed menu-search.php and searchform.php at child theme and also in main theme with no change!!!????
https://krush.co.il/

Comment: This sounds like a WordPress/server issue at this point.  The HTML above should work as long as Font Awesome is included.

Comment: Thank you all, I found it!!!, it is the product-searchform.php that is the woocommerce template for product search..